# Running Selenium on an existing Chrome Browser Window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9014")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get("https://facebook.com")
```

Learning Selenium & Python at the moment - I am trying to run Selenium on an existing Chrome Browser window, I am able to open Chrome in debugging mode from the below statement in cmd.

```
chrome.exe -remote-debuggin-port=9014 --user-data-dir="C:\selenium\chrome_testing"
```

But when I try to implement the first code in Python - I get the following error:

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9014
from chrome not reachable

Any help would be appreciated.....