# Run selenium on an already existing chrome browser?

Tags: c#, selenium

Is it possible to open my own (normal) chrome browser and have selenium run on this browser?

I saw some existing topics about this wrt. Python: [Running Selenium on an existing Chrome Browser Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63791196/running-selenium-on-an-existing-chrome-browser-window), how is someone doing this through C# and Selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Type : **chrome://version/** in browser you will get executable path of chrome.exe

copy this and close all chrome instance.

**close all chrome instance and **

**start chrome as:**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=5555
```

verify chrome is started with port open by going to localhost:5555

**Now add remote debugging port as:**

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.debuggerAddress= "127.0.0.1:5555";

var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```